# Is it possible to auto generate HTML5-AppCache Manifest files?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, service-worker, html5-appcache

I am building a web app using Angular 4 with Angular CLI. I am trying to implement App-cache for IE browsers since it does not support service workers, but the issue i'm running into is that the files static files generated by the build have a a hash code associated with them so i am unable to explicitly list the files I want to cache for App-cache. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to remove hashing from the file name in angular cli.

You can remove hash part with output-hashing option on `ng build --prod --output-hashing none`

```
output-hashing --output-hashing (short cut: -oh)
possible values: none, all, media, bundles
```

#### console output

```
xxxx$ ng build --prod --output-hashing none
Date: 2017-09-21T14:52:13.362Z                                                          
Hash: 115fd3ecef82add2dac2
Time: 6415ms
chunk {0} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 64.1 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.bundle.js (main) 5.14 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} styles.bundle.css (styles) 0 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 307 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} inline.bundle.js (inline) 1.36 kB [entry] [rendered]
xxxx$ ls
README.md       e2e         node_modules        package.json        src         tslint.json
dist            karma.conf.js       package-lock.json   protractor.conf.js  tsconfig.json
xxxx$ cd  dist
xxxx$ ls
3rdpartylicenses.txt    favicon.ico     index.html      inline.bundle.js    main.bundle.js      polyfills.bundle.js styles.bundle.css   vendor.bundle.js
xxxx$ ls -lart
total 784
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxxxx  NASDCORP\Domain Users  306976 Sep 21 10:52 vendor.bundle.js
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxxxx  NASDCORP\Domain Users       0 Sep 21 10:52 styles.bundle.css
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxxxx  NASDCORP\Domain Users   64051 Sep 21 10:52 polyfills.bundle.js
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxxxx  NASDCORP\Domain Users    5141 Sep 21 10:52 main.bundle.js
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxxxx  NASDCORP\Domain Users    1363 Sep 21 10:52 inline.bundle.js
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxxxx  NASDCORP\Domain Users     568 Sep 21 10:52 index.html
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxxxx  NASDCORP\Domain Users    5430 Sep 21 10:52 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxxxx  NASDCORP\Domain Users    3415 Sep 21 10:52 3rdpartylicenses.txt
drwxr-xr-x  17 xxxxxx  NASDCORP\Domain Users     578 Sep 21 10:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x  10 xxxxxx  NASDCORP\Domain Users     340 Sep 21 10:52 .
```

angular and cli version:

```
xxxx$ ng -v
@angular/cli: 1.4.2
node: 8.5.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.3
@angular/common: 4.4.3
@angular/compiler: 4.4.3
@angular/core: 4.4.3
@angular/forms: 4.4.3
@angular/http: 4.4.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.3
@angular/router: 4.4.3
@angular/cli: 1.4.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.3
@angular/language-service: 4.4.3
typescript: 2.3.4
```

Comment: I ran this command and my dist folder still has hash codes on all the files.

Comment: I just verified it in my local and it worked fine both the short cut and original one. `ng build --prod --oh none` and `ng build --prod --output-hashing none`. try to adjust litle in angular cli version. it might effect

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend Aniruddha Das's answer since the hashes in the file names are actually a really helpful thing:

One of the most difficult tasks you can face in SW development is cache invalidation and exactly this problem is addressed by the hashed file names. How could the users browser know when to invalidate let's say your vendor-bundle? The browser can't know there is a new version of it since it  would have to download the vendor-bundle to identify changes in it.

For exactly that reason the hash in the filename has been invented. The moment you update one of your dependencies the vendor-bundle will be generated with another hash in it's filename causing the browser to load the new file --> proper cache invalidation!

So how to achieve that?

I've created a little node script you can use for that:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let glob = require('glob');

let getFiles = (filter) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        glob(filter, (err, innerfiles) => {
            resolve(innerfiles);
        });
    });
}

let getAllFiles = (filters) => {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
        var promise = getFiles(filters[i]);
        promises.push(promise);
    }

    return Promise.all(promises).then(fileArrays => {
        var allFiles = [];

        for (var j = 0; j < fileArrays.length; j++) {
            var fileArray = fileArrays[j];
            allFiles = allFiles.concat(fileArray);
        }

        return allFiles;
    });
}

let writeFile = (fileName, content) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fs.writeFile(fileName, content, 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

getAllFiles([ "./dist/*.bundle.*", "./dist/assets/*" ]).then(files => {
    var content = `CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
`;
    for (var k = 0; k < files.length; k++) {
        var fileName = files[k];
        content += fileName.replace("./dist/", "") + `
`;
    }

    content += `
NETWORK:
*`;

    writeFile("./dist/cache.manifest", content);
});
```

Simply create a new entry in the scripts-section of your package.json:

"build:appcache": "node ./createAppCache"

(assuming you've created a script file with the content I've posted above called "createAppCache.js" in the same directory the package.json lives in).

You can run that script in your console by just typing: npm run build:appcache